# How can I avoid always adding `-Y` parameter to `ssh` command for me to be able to run `feh` and display images

Tags: ssh, images

**Situation:**

I frequently connect to one Linux Mint 18 machine, from Linux Mint 18, over SSH. I now have a need, without copying the files to me that is, to view pictures stored on the remote machine on my desktop, not in terminal in some pseudo-image format.

**Non-permanent solution:**

What works is adding `-Y` parameter to the `ssh` command. So it is fine, but I don't like always appending it to the command.

I connect like this:

```
ssh -Y herusename@192.168.0.100
```

And display image as follows:

```
feh *.jpg
```

Manual only says:

> -Y      Enables trusted X11 forwarding.  Trusted X11 forwardings are not subjected to the X11 SECURITY extension controls.

**Question:**

How can I set up SSH config file to make this option permanent?

Comment: See also: [Terminal with image support](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/187267)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
Host 192.168.0.100           # and/or preferred aliases
    Hostname 192.168.0.100   # if 'Host' is alias rather than actual hostname/IP
    User herusename
    ForwardX11 yes
    ForwardX11Trusted yes
    ... other options for this host ...
```

[man ssh_config](http://man.openbsd.org/ssh_config)

Comment: You would put this in the config file of whoever is currently executing the `ssh -Y...` command in your question.

Comment: You want this in your ssh_config, not your sshd_config.  Typically, this means a personal configuration at `~/.ssh/config`, although if you have multiple users who need to use this setup, you could put it in the global `/etc/ssh/ssh_config`.

Answer (score 1):

A simple alternative, if you're willing to use X11 forwarding for **all** `ssh` connections (implicitly):

Just define an `alias`, for `bash` you could write:

```bash
alias ssh='ssh -Y'
```

and place it to:

```bash
~/.bash_aliases
```

or even:

```bash
~/.bashrc
```